# How to create and print dynamic char arrays using null pointers? (beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, null-pointer

Our teacher wants us to create an array with variable row length using null pointers. e.g. `char* array;` in which we would then be able to input a string of any length using `scanf()`; and somehow output a normal array. How do i go from a null pointer to a usable array as described without over complicating it? (this is one of the first assignments for people who have never used c before)

This was my first failed attempt, but basically what needs to be done.I am using Dev-C++.

```
char *name;

scanf("%s",&name[0]);
printf("%s",name[0]);
```

I want the shown code to print out the input. Currently, there are no errors, but there is no print out either after the `scanf` goes off.

Comment: has the teacher talked about `malloc` and `realloc` ?

Comment: Maybe there is some misunderstanding about the topic, there is no way in Standard C to have scanf input a string of arbitrary length.  There is a non-standard extension `%ms` or something where scanf will allocate the memory